# CORS error in React frontend with Go backend

Tags: reactjs, go, fetch-api, go-gin

I have a react frontend that is served statically using go-gin. When I deploy to AWS and serve it on https I get a CORS error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/auth/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
```

It works locally and when I deploy it to a test environment with the same ssl certificate (not a wildcard certificate). My configuration of the gin router looks like this:

```
   corsConfig := cors.Config {
        AllowOrigins: []string{"https://example.com"}, 
        AllowMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowHeaders: []string{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Authorization"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    } 

    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(cors.New(corsConfig))
    authRoutes := router.Group("/auth")
    // login route
    authRoutes.POST("/login", controller.Login)
    router.StaticFS("/static", http.Dir("./frontend/build/static"))
    router.StaticFile("/", "./frontend/build/index.html")
    router.Run(":8000")
```

and my frontend api call looks like this:

```
        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH_URL}/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            //credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password
            })
        });
```

When I inspect the headers of the option calls in the web developer tools of the browser the origin matches my domain and also is https. Is it not enough to add the domain to the AllowOrigins? Do I need a wildcard certificate for this?

Comment: Your first quoted message states "Reason: CORS request did not succeed" yet you claim the OPTIONS request was successful? Please share the entire request and response headers.